# Bayes' Theorem in Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: bayes-theorem, naive-bayes

Bayes' Theorem states that:

1. $ P\left(y \mid x_1, \cdots, x_n\right)=\frac{P\left(x_1, \cdots, x_n \mid y\right) \cdot P(y)}{P\left(x_1, \cdots, x_n\right)} $
2. In Naive Bayes Classifier we can say the following:
   $ P\left(x_i \mid y, x_1, \cdots, x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, \cdots, x_n\right)=P\left(x_i \mid y\right) $
3. The previous formula allows us to write the following:
   $ P\left(y \mid x_1, \cdots, x_n\right)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n P\left(x_i \mid y\right) \cdot P(y)}{P\left(x_1, \cdots, x_n\right)} $

I however do not understand the last step. How did we go from step 2 to step 3? Could someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P(x_1, x_2 \mid y) = P(x_1 \mid y, x_2) P(x_2 \mid y)$. Generalizing to $n$ terms, we have
\begin{align}
&P(x_1, \ldots, x_n \mid y)
\\
&= P(x_1 \mid y, x_2, \ldots, x_n) P(x_2 \mid y, x_3, \ldots, x_n) \cdots P(x_{n-1} \mid y, x_n) P(x_n \mid y)
\\
&= P(x_1 \mid y) P(x_2 \mid y) \cdots P(x_{n-1} \mid y) P(x_n \mid y).
\end{align}

The second condition uses the Naive Bayes assumption: $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are conditionally independent given $y$.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is clear! I only have one more question: Could you please reference the first formula of your answer? What is the name of that formula?

Comment: So I'm talking about what comes after "Note that"

Comment: It is the definition of conditional probability. Basically $P(x_1, x_2) = P(x_1 \mid x_2) P(x_2)$ but everything conditioned on $y$. @JongeRoge

Comment: Thanks! I see it now.